# How to address the different <a> in this <li>

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

i have a slight problem with the :nth-of-type() selectors.. maybe you can help out.
I can't manage to select only the first a.
how to do this?
Thanks

```
 <nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Produkte</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Beratung</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Anfahrt</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the sass

```
li > a:nth-of-type(1){

&:before{
content:"1";
display:inline-block;
width:20px;
background:black;
border-radius:50%;
margin-right:5px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select first `li` and then `a` inside  `li:first-child a`, you can do the same with `li:nth-of-type(1) a` or `li:nth-child(1) a`

```css
li:first-child a {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Produkte</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Beratung</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Anfahrt</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: ah, sure. makes a lot of sense this way. will accept asap.thx

Comment: i did it with the :nth-child(1) nth-child(3) and so on. works for me. and removed the hr in original post. so it makes more sense here.

Comment: @Gregor If you want to select `odds` you can do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/837/